# VBA to look for information in between two dates that are written manually in a specific cell

Tags: excel, windows, date, calendar

I'm looking for a VBA code that will look in the 2nd row for specific dates.

Basically, I'm writing a "Begin" date (ex: 2018-07-01) and an "End" date (ex: 2018-07-31) and I want my code to look for everything in between, including those dates, and copy paste all the information in another excel sheet. What the function will do at the end is it'll look into many sheets for those dates and copy every bit of information that are below those dates, and paste them all into one main sheet.

What I'm attaching below is what I've done so far:

```
Sub Copie()
Sheets("1").Select
Range("B1:H1").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Per Employe").Select
Range("A4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("1").Select
Range("J1:P1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Per Employe").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("1").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Per Employe").Select
Cells(4, 1).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("1").Select
Range("B2:H2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Per Employe").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("1").Select
Range("J2:P2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Per Employe").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

What I'm trying to add is the function to look up the dates and only copy/paste the dates that were asked for in the main excel sheet, which would be "Per Employe". Would anyone have any solution to this? The cells that contain the begin and end date would be D1 & F1.